# app engine endpoints nullPointerException - isRequestRestricted

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

ok so this is what i tried so amateurly to do :\
i tried to update my appengine-sdk to 1.9.0 and after i had some mix up with old files in the libraries i decided to delete the project and create the backend from scratch, so i deleted the app engine project, then recreated the app engine backend for my client project, after that i simply added the classes files i wrote before and regenerated the endpoints libraries. all seems to be fine but when i try to run i get error 503, and the log shows nullpointerexception error, this is the relevant line from the log:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.isRequestRestricted(SystemServiceServlet.java:223)

im guessing its a configuration problem but i just don't know which :( the web.xml looks pretty much the same, i have some other servlets that i made which are not related to endpoints that works fine, this problem appears only for the endpoints generated apis

please help!